# Using a dictionary in a vim statusline expression

Tags: function, dictionary, vim, expression, statusline

I want to use an expression (function), which takes two arguments - data and a dictionary - as a statusline.

This is what I'm trying:

```
let &stl="%{Brick(statusbricks#ReportLinecount('raw'), {
        \   'brick_color': 'LineNr',
        \   'delimiter_position': 'right',
        \   'delimiter_right': '❯'
        \ })}"
```

Why does this result in the follwing error messages:

```
E722: Missing comma in Dictionary:
Press ENTER or type command to continue
E116: Invalid arguments for function Brick(statusbricks#ReportLinecount('raw'), {'brick_color': 'LineNr', 'delimiter_position': 'right', 'delimiter_right': '❯'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
E15: Invalid expression:
Brick(statusbricks#ReportLinecount('raw'), {'brick_color': 'LineNr', 'delimiter_position': 'right', 'delimiter_right': '❯'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

If I remove the dictionary in the function call it passes.
Even if I use it as a one-liner without any spaces I do get the same errors.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you place it all on one line rather than using backslash-escaped line continuation?

Comment: Yes - updated the question based on your comment.

Comment: And what if you test with a different delimiter, like `|` or `>`?  And any difference if you store the dictionary into a local var which is then passed to the function?  The dictionary itself seems to parse correctly, copy/pasting from what you've posted here.

Comment: Even passing an empty dict does not help. But storing it to a variable and then passing the var to the function works. So I'd say `%{}` does not accept "inner" curly braces. Even escaping them does not help.

Comment: I don't know what terminology vimscript uses for `%{}` to find its rules in the documentation

Comment: All I found is at `:help stl`

Comment: I see - it isn't part of broader vimscript string interpolation syntax, just statusline. `Evaluate expression between '%{' and '}' and substitute result.`. No rules listed on nesting `{}` but as you've found, it appears not to be legal.

Comment: Yes, looks like I hit either a bug or an undocumented feature. :)

Comment: However you can start the option with `%!`.

Comment: That is true but there is a significant difference: `%!` expressions get populated globally. That means all statuslines of all buffers get the expression result of the buffer being active.

Answer (score 0):

To use a dictionary in a `'statusline'` expression, a `Funcref` can be used.

For example, argument `sign_getplaced` with a dictionary:

```
let g:Sign_getplaced = function('sign_getplaced', ['', {'group':'*'}])
```

Then use `g:Sign_getplaced` in a `'statusline'` expression.

Comment: Although a custom function can also be defined to be used in `'statusline'`. Evaluating a `Funcref` is faster than evaluating a custom function.